# Mac can't resolve PC name on a local network

Tags: windows-7, macos, networking, dns

I have set up a simple http server on my local Windows 7 machine and I can access it from my Mac using the ip address and port number. However I can not access it using Windows machine's network name from Mac. At the same time I CAN access a smb share by name on the same computer from the same Mac. So if I go to `smb://dell-pc/` I will get connected, however, if I try this in browser `http://dell-pc:8000` or a simple `ping dell-pc` in terminal I will get an error

```
ping: cannot resolve dell-pc: Unknown host
```

So apparently my Mac can resolve the name when accessing smb but fails to resolve it when pinging or accessing a web server. What's the logic here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows sharing uses multicast to let other computers know it's existence. It is not the same as domain name in DNS - that's why it's working only in file sharing.
To have name on mac just add your Windows machine IP to OSX hosts file:

1. Lookup your local IP on Windows by running `ipconfig` command
2. On OSX edit hosts file `sudo nano /private/etc/hosts` put line 
   `<IP of Windows computer> dell-pc`

On local router you can also put static IP for Windows machine to not change it in future.

Comment: is there any way I could make my dell-pc advertise it's name? I would like to avoid editing hosts file, because I will also need to access this address from iPad, smart TV's browser and other devices. Btw, the pc already has a static ip address.

Comment: you need to run local DNS here you can read about it [su](http://superuser.com/questions/45789/running-dns-locally-for-home-network)