# Simple way to forward one domain to another domain in mac

Tags: networking, macos, dns

I'm trying to set up domain forwarding on my local machine so that all requests to `foo.com` are automatically redirected to `bar.com`.

I've read about [setting up a DNS server locally](https://superuser.com/questions/45789/running-dns-locally-for-home-network), but I'm wondering if there's a simpler way to accomplish this. Is there a specific configuration file I can edit to achieve domain forwarding without having to set up a DNS server?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: From a technical POV your question maked no sense. Domain Forwarding only makes sense for some services and is done at a protocol level, not in DNS.  DNS is only a lookup service and can not do any forwarding itself. If you are asking about forwarding for a particular service +like http(s) you shoukd make that part if your question and advise the program providing tjat service.   You can often override DNS Domain-> IP lookups by editing the hosts file on your computer.